# How to run two queries on mysql if first one generate no results

Tags: mysql

This is my first time here and I am a beginner so kindly bear my idiot-ism :)

I want to run two queries in mysql, from two databases in a way that if first query generate s no results then second query should search the same thing in second data base.

We have motor insurance data and there are two databases one for individual customers and second for corporate customers. We need to search vehicle by its `chasis` no or engine no. from both databases but in a sequence that if from first database no result is found then it should go for second database.

First query:

```
SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 878933
```

Second query:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_motorschedule where sw_skpoly_chasis = 878933
```

WE HAVE ONE DATABASE BUT IN IT WE HAVE TWO DIFFERENT VIEWS WHICH ARE skpoly_vw4 for individual customers and vw_motorschedule for corporate customers

Comment: What mysql function or library do you use to run mysql queries? Also, do you mean two _databases_ or two _tables_?

Comment: check the count of first query, save it in a parameter, then run the second query if the parameter is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS( )` after executing the first query.

that is, 
before running the second query check if `SELECT FOUND_ROWS( )>0`

EDIT: 
Here is an example

```
SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 878933

DECLARE @rows INT
SET @rows= FOUND_ROWS();
if (@rows>0)
SELECT * FROM vw_motorschedule where sw_skpoly_chasis = 878933
```

Comment: Dear i would appreciate if you can provide me with a query.will be highly obliged

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM DATABASE1
WHERE database1_CHASIS = 12345**

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM DATABASE2 
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND database2_chasis= 12345**
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df91d/3)

### Update 1

Per conversation, you are getting mysql error number 1222. This is happening because in table `skpoly_vw4` & `vw_motorschedule` number of fields are not same. For UNION ALL, the fields has to be same.

E.g. In table1 you have id and name and in table2 you have id, fname, lname then if you try to use `UNION ALL` with `select *` it won't work as in table1 there are 2 columns however in table2 there are 3 columns.

Hope you got what I meant to say.

Also read **[select * from two tables with different # of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660788/select-from-two-tables-with-different-of-columns).**

Comment: Query : SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 878933 UNION ALL SELECT *  FROM vw_motorschedule  WHERE FOUND_ROWS() ...

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM skpoly_vw4
WHERE CHASIS = 878933
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM vw_motorschedule ' at line 2

Comment: @OwaisAlam : you are missing * after `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Also you are putting some number to compare after FOUND_ROWS(). like FOUND_ROWS() = 0

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM skpoly_vw4
WHERE CHASIS = 878933

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM vw_motorschedule 
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND sw_skpoly_chasis = 878933
ERROR-Query : SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 878933 UNION ALL SELECT *  FROM vw_motorschedule  WHERE FOUND_ROWS()...

Error Code : 1222
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @OwaisAlam : Could you please provide sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2 ?? I believe you are using MYSQL

Comment: yes iam using mysql
and sir can you please tell me hwo to put date function say if i want to download data ranging from current system date to exactly two years back.
select * from skpoly_vw4 where date??????? your guidance needed

Comment: SELECT * FROM `skpoly_vw4`  WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y') < 2010
i do not want to put 2010 i mean it automatically takes 2 years back..so that every date results will be generated for two years ranging from system date to two years back

Comment: @OwaisAlam : what is datatype of the date column? timestamp or datetime? say mydate = '2012-12-30' (format should be yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: we have a column which is STARTDATE in start date date is written as 2007-10-25 00:00:00

Comment: we have following columns in VIEW skpoly_vw4
BRANCH POLICYNO ISSUEDATE STARTDATE
startdate format is timedate and date appears as 2007-10-25 00:00:00
i want to run query which takes data where risk startd ate is between system date and two years back date

Comment: SELECT  * 
FROM    skpoly_vw4
WHERE   STARTDATE BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1460 DAY AND SYSDATE()
IT IS WORKING.THANK YOU DEAR FOR PUSHING ME TO THINK :) BUT BRO I NEED ANSWER OF MY FIRST ENQUIRY.HOW TO RUN TWO QUERIES WHEN ONE GENERATE NO RESULT

Comment: @OwaisAlam : I have answered that. What problem you are facing there?

Comment: @OwaisAlam : I got what is your problem. The problem is that in both table the # of fields are different. While using UNION ALL, fields in BOTH table should be same. Hope you got my point... E.g. in table1 you have id and name AND in table2 you have id, fname, lname then if you try to do UNION ALL, it won't work... Could you please let me know table structure of both tables?

Comment: @OwaisAlam : see my updated answer. Hope you got what is the problem.

Comment: @OwaisAlam : Did you get where the problem is?

Comment: Dear fahim
yes i got the point.but after making changes in your demo still i am having this error

Comment: @OwaisAlam : Can you put your query in your question? Edit question and put your query where you are getting problem. Also just to confirm, you are using MY SQL. Right?

Comment: Dear.we have two tables first one is skpoly_vw4 in this we have data for individual customers who are insured.second is vw_motorschedule.in it we have data for corporate customers.let say is i want to search a vehicle from its engine no or registration no i first have to check in first table and then in second.
First query:
SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 878933
Second query:
SELECT * FROM vw_motorschedule where sw_skpoly_chasis = 878933
i need a single query which search from first table then if vehicle is not found then it runs query in second table

Comment: both tables have chasis no of vehicle but column names are different.in first table column name is CHASIS in second table column name is SW_SKPOLY_CHASIS. we are using MYSQL.i need a query which first check data in first table and then in second.

Comment: further fahim can u tell how can i update data in a server in my department which we have created from a server in another depart.we have login for that server.what i did is that first i downloaded all the data from other server and imported it in our server database which have same columns.now daily data is updated in second server(it is linked with branches) how can we update data in ourserver?iam not an it guy iam a financial modelling guy and have connected excel with mysql all i need is your guidance.

Comment: @OwaisAlam : how many questions in one post?? I have also provided demo where it is working. OK?? That means there is problem with your syntax... get that resolved... I HAVE PROVIDED SIMPLE SOLUTION STILL YOU HAVE DOUBTS?? WE ARE NOT GOING TO SPOON FOOD YOU. ***DON'T BE LAZY***

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DATABASE1 WHERE database1_CHASIS = 12345");

if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DATABASE2 where database2_chasis= 12345");
}

$customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: thanks let me check i will get back to you.still iam thankfull for your kind responses.thaks alot

Comment: $QUERY = mysql_query( SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 12345);

IF(mysql_num_rows($QUERY)==0){
Query : $query = mysql_query( SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 12345)

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query = mysql_query( SELECT * FROM skpoly_vw4 WHERE CHASIS = 12345)' at line 1
 
   $QUERY = mysql_query( SELECT * FROM vw_motorschedule WHERE sw_skpoly_chasis = 12345 );
}

$customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($QUERY);

Comment: It's not particularly helpful to just dump code and messages in a comment. You should edit your question to include the snippet you tried, and what the error was. That way we don't have to read every comment, and also parse out obfuscated messages from them.