# Need a sql query for this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi all please help me wire a sql query for the scenario

Table

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
| ID | country | region | restaurant | locationcode |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | IND     | DL     | xyz        |          100 |
|  2 | IND     | DL     | yzc        |          111 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
```

SELECT all items ---

```
if condition matched with country,region,restaurant,locationcode
  If not then all items that matched condition with country,region,restaurant
      if not then all items that matched the condition with country,region
```

Can I do that using sql query or I have to handle that using application logic?

Comment: Please provide a sample expected output

Comment: @Ullas SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE region='DL' AND country='IND' AND restaurant='xyz' AND locationcode='100'; If no result found then select id from mytable on basis of country and region.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? And are you using variables for searching by country, region etc.?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes I am using variables and server is MySql

Comment: which condition matche? Please specify the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is kind of verbose but it should work. Use a `CASE` to choose from the options, and use the existence of those rows as the condition for choosing.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE 
CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE region='DL' AND country='IND'
                   AND restaurant='xyz' AND locationcode='100')
       THEN region='DL' AND country='IND' AND restaurant='xyz' AND locationcode='100'
     WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE region='DL' AND country='IND')
       THEN region='DL' AND country='IND'
     WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE region='DL' )
       THEN region = 'DL';
     END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved like this using `IF`

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM mytable mt
WHERE
    IF(
        mt.region='DL' 
        AND mt.country='IND' 
        AND mt.restaurant='xyz' 
        AND mt.locationcode='100',
        1,
        IF(
            mt.region='DL' 
            AND mt.country='IND' 
            AND mt.restaurant='xyz',
            1,
            IF(
                mt.region='DL' 
                AND mt.country='IND'
            ,1,
            'Nothing Found')
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if we want to do in SQL then better way is to do in SQL block.

Similar to example given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222053/555953